# HttpClient, Post Method POST Method

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

Trying to do a Post with httpClient with my app i have this line of code

```
  public ActionResult Create(LutUsers users)
     {

     HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/user/create", 
     **httpcontent**).Result;

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

        }

    return View();
}
```

What Should my httpcontent be? i'm using a web api to post my data

THank you for helping

Comment: hi, interesting might want to check this out https://kiewic.com/2014-10-23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync

Comment: Only you know what you need to post. `users`, I guess? Side note, don't block the call with `.Result`. Make the method async and `await` it.

Comment: @jspcal is that  **"{ \"firstName\": \"John\" }"** the content of my json?

Comment: [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: API documentation is likely to specify what you need to send and what it accepts. Could be a json (probably), could be XML (Less likely these days)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use async method for it you can use it like:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
StringContent postContent = new StringContent("{ \"firstName\": \"John\" }");

var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/user/create", postContent);
var resString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If you need synchronous method you can create tasks for it:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
StringContent postContent = new StringContent(content);

var task = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/user/create", postContent)); 
task.Wait();
```

Comment: StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?

now i have this error  using String content , do you have an idea?

Comment: var user = new LutUsers();
            var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/user/findusers", stringContent);

            Response.Write(response);

Comment: StatusCode 405 is showing if the receiver side does not allow the Post method for the url you should try to use PutAsync with the same parameters. But it is surely an error on the method (the other side controller doesn't accept your POST method, so it is waiting for GET or PUT)